# Is there a 29.5 day cycle of neutrotransmitters released from the claustrum in our brains?

Tags: biology, physiology

According to multiple 'spiritual' websites (like [this](https://www.soulwarriorsretreat.com/sacred-secretion) one), there is a 29.5 cycle in the human body.

> Every 29.5 Days, A Seed Is Born That Gifts You With An Opportunity For A Physiological & Spiritual Rebirth...
>
> [...]
>
> Beginning around age 12, every month when the moon enters your Sun Sign (Vedic or True Sidereal), your claustrum (located in your cerebrum) acts like an antenna and picks up on the incoming frequencies from the Sun reflected by the moon.
>
> These energetic frequencies initiate 2 processes:
>
> A neurotransmitter is released from your claustrum that signals your pineal and pituitary glands to release their sacred secretions.[...] The sacred secretion from your claustrum is then differentiated into electric and magnetic portions by both glands and is referred to as the Christos Oil, or Chrism Oil.
>
> An energetic seed, or psycho-somatic germ, is pulled from the vibrational frequencies flowing through your cerebrospinal fluid that keep you stuck in your reptilian brain (fight / flight / freeze) and locked out of your holy temple body and divine mind.

Does this have a scientific basis?

**Update**
I found that the human body might react to the [lunar cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_phase) in some way. In [this study](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.3109/00016348609158228), menstruation was linked to the new moon. Since the lunar cycle is 29.5 days, that could be related to this question.

Comment: I note that [the moon's phases repeat every 29.5 days](https://www.iop.org/explore-physics/moon/phases-and-orbits-moon).

Comment: Yes, this is also mentioned on those 'spiritual' websites.

Comment: "*when the moon enters your Sun Sign … Does this have a scientific basis?*" — I.e. is there any scientific explanation of how the Moon knows and remembers the sun sign of each individual person, or is there any scientific mechanism by which the Moon can selectively affect specific people on Earth?

Comment: I agree that the part about Sun Sign might be illogical. However, there might be a different scientific principle which can link the claustrum to the phases of the moon.

Comment: I dunno what's so "sacred" about it. Many creatures are influenced by the lunar cycle. Please see this study: [The lunar cycle: effects on human and animal behavior and physiology](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/16407788/)

Comment: _"According to multiple 'spiritual' websites"_ That should usually be your first tipoff that it does not have a scientific basis.